# How to calculate 5/1 + 5/2 +5/3 +5/4 + 5/5 in o(1) using C programming?

Tags: c, math

How to calculate the sum of *integer divisions*  5/1 + 5/2 + 5/3 +5/4 + 5/5 in O(1) using C integer division where 5/2 = 2, 5/3 = 1, 5/4 = 1 and so on...
I can find it using for loop but time complexity is O(n) for that.

Comment: You try to find the relevant [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A006218) and then implement it :) -- *`a(n) = n * ( log(n) + 2*gamma - 1 ) + O(sqrt(n))`* if my find was correct

Comment: Complexity of your for loop is not o(n) it is o(5) which is o(1)

Comment: Pretty sure OP means N/1 + N/2 + ... + N/N, but this is completely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```c
short sum() {
  return 5/1 + 5/2 + 5/3 + 5/4 + 5/5;
}
```

Since the number of computations is fixed, this will be θ(1). It will probably even be evaluated at compile time, so the *actual compiled code* will likely look equivalent to this:

```c
short sum() {
  return 10;
}
```

> I can find it using for loop but time complexity is O(n) for that.

Actually, it isn't. Since the number of iterations is bounded by a constant, it will still be O(1), even with a loop.

Comment: Equally, if you write it as a loop, it'll probably be unrolled... :)

Comment: Indeed. And, since the number of iterations is bounded by 5, it is going to be constant time, even if the loop isn't unrolled.

Answer (score 0):

compilers are quite smart :)

```
int foo(void)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        result += 5/i;
    return result;
}
```

```
foo:
        mov     eax, 10
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E55Pjh

The best way to learn is to test yourself